# Jackson creating cookie

Tags: java, json, cookies, jackson

I am trying to create a cookie in the JSON format using jackson library.Below is the code.
Problem is when I view the cookie value in the browser, I am seeing
"{\"name\":\"D\”}" instead of {"name":"D"}. I tried setting a custom CharacterEscapes with the JsonFactory and setting esc['"'] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_NONE but that didn't work.Any help would be appreciated?
BTW I am using Tomcat container for deployment and cookiesContent is a map.

```
      ObjectMapper om =  new ObjectMapper();
      om.getFactory().setCharacterEscapes(custom());

    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("name", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(cookiesContent));
    cookie.setDomain(domain);
    cookie.setPath("/");
    cookie.setMaxAge(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    cookie.setSecure(false);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [HTTP State Management Mechanism specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1) (which deals with Cookies) states that you can't have the double quote character in the value of the cookie unless it wraps the entire thing.

Don't (try to) put JSON in cookies.

Comment: unfortunately thats not an option at this point. but thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Java Using valid JSON (ie. unescaped) in cookies is not an option either.